# Создание файла в java

Tags: java

Как создавать файл в java, чтобы он стал частью package?
Тоесть, находился в одной папке с java файлами?
Путь к папке через C:// не подходит, т.к. файл должен создаваться на разных устройствах.
И как его прописать впоследствии для открытия?

Comment: Если править отдельный jar, то это еще куда ни шло. А вот если в том, который запускаешь... Как-то искал инфу об этом. Как аргументировали - не помню. Толи перезапуск нужен, толи еще что-то, но суть была в том что оно того не стоило.

Comment: А для чего вы создаёте этот файл?

Comment: @LEQADA это html, который данные отображает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вы можете получить путь к папке проекта как

```
String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
```

и затем просто создавать файлы в папке проекта как

```
File newFile = new File(path + "\file1.txt");
```