# Сохранение данных в CSV файл

Tags: java, android, csv

после сохранения в файл при открытии с excel кодировка бывает не понятной(только если текст на русском), а через notepad++ все читабельно, в чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста

```
String filename = "mytest.csv";
String entry = "Задача" +";"+"первая";
try {
    FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    out.write(entry.getBytes());
    out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

и если не сложно подскажите что почитать для создания csv файла в android

Comment: вы сами ответили на свой вопрос - дело в кодировке. Значит вам надо строку записывать в другой кодировке.

Comment: ну а как исправить это?

Comment: написал отдельным ответом

Comment: если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос - не забывайте закрывать вопрос, нажав на галку)

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как проверить файл на существование? если он есть то удалить его и записать информацию заново, чтоб к одному файлу не добавлялась вся информация

Comment: поправил свой ответ, смотрите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте или в файл сохранять в нужной кодировке:

```
// Строка Unicode
String string = "...";
// Записываем строку в текстовый файл в кодировке Cp866
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter   // класс с методами записи строк
  (new OutputStreamWriter          // класс-преобразователь
     (new FileOutputStream         // класс записи байтов в файл
        ("file.txt"), "Cp866");
pw.println(string);  // записываем строку в файл
pw.close();
```

или, например, строку сразу записывать в нужной кодировке

```
// Строка Unicode
String string = "...";
// Записываем строку в текстовый файл в двух кодировках (Cp866 и Cp1251)
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("file.txt"); // класс записи байтов в файл
// Записываем строку в кодировке Cp866
os.write( string.getBytes("Cp866") );
// Записываем строку в кодировке Cp1251
os.write( string.getBytes("Cp1251") );
os.close();
```

Если файл у вас уже существует, можно сделать проверку в самом начале и удалить его:

```
File f = new File("1.txt");
if (f.exists())
  f.delete();
```

Comment: спасибо большое помогло))))

Comment: вы обратились к файлу private static String fileName = "C://blog/a.txt"; а как это сделать в android

Comment: @java я уже поправил, первый способ всегда выручит) а в андроид обращайться можно, я думаю, [как тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479023/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java/479025#479025)