# Каким способом лучше указывать путь к файлу в программе на языке Java? Где лучше хранить используемые программой файлы?

Tags: java

Можно прописать абсолютный путь к файлу, скажем вот так:

```
Image img = new ImageIcon("G:\\img.png").getImage();
```

Насколько я понимаю, так делать совсем плохо, ибо мы не знаем, куда пользователь сохранит нашу программу.

Можно прописать относительный путь к файлу, скажем вот так:

```
Image img = new ImageIcon("img.png").getImage();
```

Но тогда (если только я правильно понял из проделанных экспериментов) чтобы получить полный путь к файлу JVM делает "конкатенацию" текущей директории с прописанным относительным путём. Т.е. если я запускаю программу такой командой:

```
G:\program\bin>java -jar Program.jar
```

То JVM будет искать файл по такому расположению:

```
G:\program\bin\img.png
```

Насколько я понимаю, так делать совсем плохо, ибо мы не знаем, с какой директории будет запускать пользователь нашу программу.

Можно делать что-то вообще интересное и непростое, типа такого:

```
Image img = new ImageIcon( this.getClass().getResource("img.png") ).getImage();
```

Здесь поиск файла будет происходить из пакета, где находится класс `this.getClass()`. (т.е. та самая "конкатенация" происходит с путём к пакету класса)

Но ведь наверное плохо мешать файлы классов с файлами ресурсов?

Или даже так:

```
Image img = new ImageIcon( this.getClass().getResource("/img.png") ).getImage();
```

Здесь поиск файла происходит в директориях `classpath`. Но по идее, тогда может оказаться несколько подходящих файлов? И что же это будет?!

В общем вопросы:
Правильно ли то, что я написал?
Какие ещё способы существуют?
Когда какой способ использовать?
Какой способ наилучший (если он существует)?

Comment: intellij idea лучше всего так Run -> Edit configuration -> working derictory(указать рабочую директорию)

Comment: Хранить изображения и другие ресурсы не нуждающиеся в редактировании внутри JAR - нормальная практика. Обычно создают отдельный каталог `images` на одном уровне с корнем пакета, либо копируют его туда при сборке JAR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Общим ответом на это будет просто слово "зависит" - главный вопрос в том, с чем вы работаете. Как правило, java-приложения распространяются в виде jar-архивов, и если у вас есть распространяемые с приложением *ресурсы* (например, иконки), то они должны либо оказаться именно там, среди классов, либо, если вы распространяете приложение в виде архива и отдельных ресурсов снаружи архива, то вам нужно самому находить расположение jar-файла и вручную восстанавливать путь к ресурсом по аналогии с working directory. В случае, если вы пишете некоторую утилиту, которая обрабатывает аргументы, то вам, скорее всего, придется иметь дело из абсолютными, и с относительными путями - если вы пишете, скажем, ресайзер изображений, то вызов `java -jar path/resizer.jar image.png 300x400` потребует простого проброса аргумента внутрь ImageIcon напрямую, без вообще какого-либо анализа.

Другими словами, все описанные методы имеют свое применение, и являются более или менее предпочтительными в зависимости от ситуации; каждый из них не *чем-то плох*, а *неприменим в текущей ситуации*. Если вопрос заключается в поиске ресурсов приложения, то лучше всего либо закидывать в jar, либо искать место установки приложения и отсчитывать от него (т.к. working dir может оказатсья любым).

Comment: Т.е. в jar-архиве создаётся отдельная папка, в которую заносятся файлы ресурсов, а обращение к ним происходит с помощью 4-ого способа, да?

Comment: @zer_ik да, все верно

Answer (score 1):

Никто не мешает вам использовать ваши изображения и другие файлы в той же директории без абсолютного пути:

```
String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
```

Храните просто изображения, предположим, в папке img, сам .jar файл будет в корневой папке. В результате тянете ваши изображения по пути `path + "\img"`.

[Подобная тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479023/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java/479025#479025) (только с созданием файлов).

Comment: Либо вы предложили плохую идею, либо я её не понял.
В переменной path будет хранится текущая директория. Таким образом использование path + "\img" эквивалентно использованию "img". (посмотрите второй по счёту способ, который я описал в самом вопросе)