# Как подняться на три папки выше в описании адреса?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Каталог с иконками для кнопок лежит тремя папками выше, при обращении такого вида не видит картинку:  -> `../../../images/newk.png` (хотя на две папки выше видел  `../../images/newk.png`, когда перемещала ), да и абсолютный адрес тоже не видит: работает только с локальным адресом(если положить картинки в корень), передаю адрес как `String` для создания в итоге кнопки-иконки.
[image: код]

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496747/197447

Answer (score 3):

Вот так надо:

```
./images/newk.png
```